# LXDE panel and desktop asks for confirmation every time I click an icon

Tags: debian, lxde

After upgrading to Debian 10, whenever I click an icon in the LXDE Panel or Desktop (lxpanel 0.10.0), I get a confirmation dialog asking me if I really wanted to open the application I just clicked the icon for. This is becoming quite annoying, is there any way to turn this off, I haven't found any settings to disable this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=248380#p1516491

File manager

Edit

Preferences

General

Do not ask option on executable launch

Take out the tick

Comment: Thanks! It didn't occur to me to look in the File Manager's preferences for this.